# If no decimals, add default ones

Tags: php, decimal, default, number-formatting

Having the following decimal numbers:

- 47.44
- 180.11
- 340
- 12.39
- 25

I was wondering, how can I add a default `.00` to those numbers, that have no decimals?

Comment: `sprintf('%0.2f', $val)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `number_format()` like that:

```
number_format($number, 2);
```

It'll always return number with two decimals. Also it'll separate thousands with ',' (if you don't want that, add '' as fourth parameter).